# Laravel 5.2 - Adding laravelcollective/html 5.2 throws errors

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel v5.2 and have followed the instructions below to install laravelcollective/html, but it still throws errors:

Browser: FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 119: Call to undefined method Collective\Html\FormFacade::isDeferred()

Artisan: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Call to undefined method Collective\Html\FormFacade::isDeferred()

Also tried 5.2.*-dev, but get the same errors.

Hope someone can help!

Command:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Added to composer.json "require" group:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
composer update
```

Added to config/app.php in providers group:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

In aliases group:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the actual class files exist in the vendor directory?

Comment: Yes, the class files are there.

Comment: Can you show the source code of the function you are trying to call?

Comment: Heh. Haven't gotten that far yet.  This is just the initial setup.  I'm doing a tutorial (https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-1/) and Part 2 begins with requiring laravelcollective/html.  The author is is using 5.0, I'm on 5.2. Maybe I should just start over using L5.0.

Comment: Just to check you did run the "composer update" before editing you "config/app.php" file. I don't think much has changed between 5.0 and 5.2 but it's probably worth rolling back to 5.0 for your tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for responding, RCrowt.  It was a stupid mistake on my part - I had the facades under service providers instead of aliases.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it is not too late, but maybe answer on your question will be useful for a future reference. So, here is step by step:

1) In the root of your laravel package open composer.json file in "require" group should be added this line:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
```

It should look similar to:
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
    },

2) Open command prompt or Git Bash and update the composer with command:

```
composer update
```

The composer will update within about one or two minutes.

3) Open config/app.php add this line in providers group:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and don't forget to separate the previous class by comma. It should look like:

```
Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

4) In the same file in aliases group add these alias:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

so it should look like:

```
'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

I hope this will help to anyone who use Laravel 5.2.*